# Android IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalargumentexception

I've been struggling with this for some time now. I have a rather complex system consisting of a library module and app modules.

The library modules contains 
Activities: AbstractActivity <- AbstractListActivity
Fragments: AbstractFragment <- (AbstractListFragment & AbstractEditFragment)

app module contains 
Activities: WineListActivity ( -> AbstractListActivity)
Fragments: WineListFragment & EditWineFragment ( -> AbstractList & AbstractEdit fragments)

At startup, the WineListActivity is loaded and shown with WineListFragment. When a wine is selected from list the fragment is replaced with EditFragment. When the user presses the back or save button, the app should execute activity onbackpressed and show the WineListFragment again. Here is were the crash occurs. Any help with this would be appreciated. I've been looking into this for some time now. Error:

```
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.toteki.winetaster, PID: 4148
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c004f (com.toteki.winetaster:id/content_container) for fragment WineListFragment{423e51d0 #0 id=0x7f0c004f}
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1018)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:958)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1625)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:561)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onBackPressed(FragmentActivity.java:166)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2193)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2664)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2423)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.internal.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:50)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:224)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2017)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3848)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3822)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3395)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3445)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3414)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3521)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3422)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3395)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3445)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3414)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3422)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3395)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3445)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3414)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3554)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3714)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2021)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1715)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1706)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:1998)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
09-12 20:50:50.625 4148-4148/com.toteki.winetaster E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Classes:
AbstractActivity

```
public abstract class AbstractActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String TAG = "AbstractActivity";

    protected AbstractFragment fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_abstract);
    }

    public void addFragment(AbstractFragment fragment) {
        Log.d(TAG, "addFragment");

        this.fragment = fragment;

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transaction.addToBackStack(this.fragment.TAG);

        transaction.add(com.toteki.library.R.id.content_container, this.fragment, this.fragment.TAG).commit();
    }

    public void replaceFragment(AbstractFragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack) {
        Log.d(TAG, "replaceFragment");

        this.fragment = fragment;

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if(addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(this.fragment.TAG);
        }

        transaction.replace(com.toteki.library.R.id.content_container, this.fragment, this.fragment.TAG).commit();
    }

    public abstract void onTaskSuccessful(String tag);
    public abstract void onTaskFailure(String tag);
}
```

WineListActivity

```
public class WineListActivity extends AbstractListActivity {
    public final static String TAG = "WineListActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        WineDataSource.instance().open(this);
        WineDataSource.instance().delete();
        WineDataSource.instance().close(this);

        addFragment(new WineListFragment());
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClicked(Rateable r) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("currentWine", r);

        AbstractFragment fragment = new EditWineFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        replaceFragment(fragment, true);
    }
}
```

WineListFragment

```
public class WineListFragment extends AbstractListFragment {
    public final static String TAG = "WineListFragment";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Wine w = new Wine();
            w.setName("Test " + i);
            WineController.instance().create(w);
        }

        adapter = new WineListAdapter(activity, WineController.instance().getList());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        return v;
    }
}
```

WineListAdapter

```
public class WineListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private AbstractActivity activity;
    private List<Wine> wineList;

    public WineListAdapter(AbstractActivity activity, List<Wine> wineList) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.wineList = wineList;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_wine_list, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Wine wine = wineList.get(position);
        ((ViewHolder) holder).getBinding().setVariable(BR.wine, wine);
        ((ViewHolder) holder).getBinding().executePendingBindings();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return wineList.size();
    }

    private class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        private ItemWineListBinding binding;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            v.setOnClickListener(this);

            binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(v);
        }

        public ViewDataBinding getBinding() {
            return binding;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((AbstractListActivity) activity).onListItemClicked(binding.getWine());
        }
    }
}
```

EditWineFragment

```
public class EditWineFragment extends AbstractEditFragment {
    public final static String TAG = "EditWineFragment";

    private FragmentEditWineBinding currentWineBinding;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null) {
            currentRateable = (Wine) bundle.getSerializable("currentWine");
        }

        if(currentRateable == null) {
            currentRateable = new Wine();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_wine, container, false);

        currentWineBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(activity, R.layout.fragment_edit_wine);
        currentWineBinding.setWine((Wine) currentRateable);

        return v;
    }

    protected void actionSave() {
        activity.onBackPressed();

        currentRateable = currentWineBinding.getWine();
        new CreateTask(activity, WineDataSource.instance(), WineController.instance()).execute(currentRateable);
    }
}
```

acitivty_abstract.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#f9d107">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_edit_wine.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <data>
        <variable name="wine" type="com.toteki.winetaster.model.Wine"/>
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:background="#e90f0f">

        <com.toteki.library.view.CustomEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            custom:input="@{wine.name}"
            custom:header="@string/header_name"
            custom:hint="@string/hint_name"
            android:background="#09ef06" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Edit: I removed the onCreateView of the EditWineFragment and everything worked fine when pressing the back button (except that the actual layout is not shown). So I'm guessing that the way I create/add the view layout for the EditWineFragment is the problem. But what exactly is going wrong I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the data binding. According to the documentation of `setContentView`, the layout of the activity is replaced:

> Set the Activity's content view to the given layout and return the associated binding.

Therefore, when you end the fragment and the FragmentManager tries to reinstate the `WineListFragment` the `content_container` is gone. So, the previous fragment cannot be placed in the layout and an exception is thrown.

Comment: I just tried that, but it didnt work. I had the addToBackstack in the addFragment method before, but both didnt work

Comment: I updated my answer now you found out that removing `onCreateView` resolves the problem.

Comment: Yeah! I'm happy. thanks to your question I fixed it!. I had to change the line `currentWineBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(activity, R.layout.fragment_edit_wine);` to `currentWineBinding = DataBindingUtil.bind(v);`. This fixed the whole error!